# Can - and should I - merge between repositories on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have an embedded C project on a quite old repository with 10+ years of history. Now I need to port this whole project to a new platform, different CPU, some different APIs. The old platform still needs to be supported for bugfixes and some minor new features, which means occasionally there will be new code and bug fixes which need to be merged from the new version into the old version.

Now I see two ways of doing that:

1) Just create a branch "legacy" for the old platform, do my porting on master, and merge what I need to merge from master to legacy

2) Check out the existing code, port it to the new platform, and create a new repository from that. This would mean, that I occasionally need to merge come code between these two repos, but I have a new and fresh repo without 10 years of old history and 50+ abandoned branches in it.

Is the second way doable, i.e. is it possible to merge (or cherrypick) between different repos with common ancestors?

If so which way would you recommend and why?

Any thoughts are highly appreciated!

Edit: Another reason for option 2) would be that it would be simpler to do, because I need to use a new IDE for the new platform, i.e. I need to create a new project and copy the code from the old project into the new project. I would then have to somehow explain git that this project I have created is the new master, without having pulled from the repo before.

Comment: What benefits do you imagine you will get by creating a second repository?  It seems that what you're doing -- continuing development of a project that may still need patches against older code -- is almost exactly the use case for which git was designed, and seems quite suitable to a single repository.

Comment: Creating clones takes longer and longer over the years because the history is so big, and I hope to get more efficiency.

Comment: Do you create clones often?

Comment: Not really often. You are right, it is probably not an important reason. It is more a feeling of having a "clean start", but maybe it is a bad idea to follow feelings in IT. Please see my edit above to understand why I thought about option 2) in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation: a 20-year C repository that has to work on a 25-year-old 8-bit platform, and on a very fresh ARM chip. The old C code is laced with inline assembly, so I had to factor it all out. Then I wrote a clang rewriter that implemented some modern C features, and recast them in terms that the old C compiler could understand. For example, inline functions were expanded in place based on the always-inline attribute, whereas the old code formerly used macros for that (ugh). It also emitted some of the necessary inline assembly that works around bugs in the old compiler. So, I’d suggest that you do it only after getting yourself familiar with clang-based source-to-source rewriting: otherwise it’s very hard to write readable code that doesn’t trigger a million warnings and stylistic advice on modern compilers. I will probably write an IR-to-C backend, as that would take care of most missed optimizations that the original compiler couldn’t have dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your new github repo compact and focused without losing history, because you can fetch/push arbitrary histories anywhere, orphan your new history and if you find you need something from the old, fetch it from there and browse/cherrypick/whatever to your heart's content.  Fetching utility code  from a private utilities repo is a handy stunt.